# Mapear um campo do tipo CHAR no banco de dados para um campo do tipo bool no C#, com FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, tipagem, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

No banco de dados tenho um campo `ATIVO` do tipo `CHAR(1)`, onde `'T' = true` e `'F' = false`.

Hoje, em minha aplicação estou contornando este problema com uma "gambiarra", onde mapiei meu atributo `Ativo`, como `string` e criei outro atributo `bool IsAtivo` que faz algo similar a isso:

```cs
public bool IsAtivo
{
    get { return Ativo == "T"; }
    set { Ativo = value ? "T" : "F"; }
}
```

> Nem precisam comentar que é horroroso que eu já to sabendo, até por isso quero melhorar, quando implementei isso não tive tempo para procurar forma melhorar.

Então gostaria de saber se conhecem alguma forma de mapear isso para o [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate), através do mapeamento pelo [fluent-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate)?

```cs
// Acredito que alguma configuração aqui pode resolver meu problema
Map(t => t.Ativo, "ATIVO")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No NHibernate existe um UserType abstrato e específico para este caso, chamado `CharBooleanType`, que permite que você mapeie um tipo `char` como `bool`. Crie uma class que herda deste tipo e sobreescreva as propriedades `TrueString` e `FlaseString`:

```
public class ActiveBoolType : CharBooleanType 
{
   public ActiveBoolType()
         : base(new AnsiStringFixedLengthSqlType(1)) { }

   protected override string TrueString 
   {
       get { return "T"; }
   }

   protected override string FalseString 
   {
       get { return "F"; }
   }

   public override string Name 
   {
       get { return "inverted_bool"; }
   }
}
```

Depois basta mapea-lo da como um tipo customizado apontando para este tipo.

**FluentNhibernate:**

```
Map(x => x.IsAtivo).Column("ATIVO").CustomType<ActiveBoolType>();
```

**HBM.XML**

```
<property name="IsAtivo" 
          column="ATIVO" 
          type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.ActiveBoolType, MyAssembly" />
```

[Neste link](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/02/10/generic-nhibernate-user-type-base-class/) fala um pouco sobre a criação de `UserTypes`.

Comment: +1 Interessante. Implementação do **[`NHibernate.Type.CharBooleanType`](https://gitorious.org/nhibernate/mainline/source/42f6aa2dcc5a8ced53d1e7e9746f014dce5482d8:nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Type/CharBooleanType.cs).**

Comment: Obrigado pela referência Miguel. :)

Comment: @FelipeOriani, muito obrigado, pela ajuda, muito interessante essa forma. Funcionou perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: Seria possível também utilizar o EnumCharType<T> da mesma forma?
No base de dados legada tenho um campo que é char(1) "F" ou "J". Pessoa Física ou Jurídica, e eu gostaria de mapear para um boleano.